# pdo_mysql extension is not installed error on magento2

Tags: magento2, php-pdo

I'm facing this type of extension error on local machine. I also Checked pdo_mysql extension install on my server.It show enable status during execuate commond .
which is :
 php -i|grep PDO
It Shows PDO support => enabled
But execuate Some indexing commond it seems error.
I h've attched Screen Shot on my terminal Captured.
I'm using php 5.6.20 and mysql v5.6+
[image: look once]

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed the extension?

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-pdo-mysql
```

Comment: I already apply this commond. but still not fixed.

Comment: Did you restart your webserver?